# Why wont it paste? Using Variables and offset cell references

Tags: vba, excel

Object doesnt support this property or method. Only happens on the .Paste section in this code. Please help, because I am perplexed. I have tried to simplify the code as much as posible to simply select the cell, copy the cell, select target, and paste. Something is missing here...

```
Sub AIM36DBOCompare()
Dim n As Integer
n = 2
Dim PasteCount As Integer
Dim Value1 As String
Dim Date1 As String
Dim c As Range
PasteCount = 41
    Range("AD2:AD1000").Copy Destination:=Range("S41" & Lastrow)
    Do While n <= 1000
        If Cells(26, n) <> 0 Then
'--------------------------------------------
            With Worksheets(1).Range("b2:b10000")
                Set c = .Find(Cells(n, 26), LookIn:=xlValues)
                If Not c Is Nothing Then
                    Do
                        Date1 = c.Offset(0, -1).Address
                        Value1 = c.Offset(0, 3).Address
                        If Abs(Cells(n, 25) - Range(Date1).Value) <= 10 Then
                            Range(Value1).Select
                            Selection.Copy
                            Cells(PasteCount, 17).Select
                            Selection.Paste
                            PasteCount = PasteCount + 1
                            Exit Do
                        End If
                            Set c = .Find(Cells(n, 26).Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
                    Loop While Not c Is Nothing
                End If
            End With
'--------------------------------------------
        End If
        If Cells(11, n) = 0 Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    n = n + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do `Selection.Paste` (As you have just observed). If you call `Paste` on the sheet, it will paste to your selection, try this instead

`ActiveSheet.Paste`

Answer (score 4):

Or if you just want to copy the value, skip the whole select and paste:

```
Cells(PasteCount, 17).Value = Range(Value1).Value
```